# solving an equation for the square of the variable?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given a expression (polynomial, or any equation in general) such as

```
a s^2+b = 0
```

I want to solve for s^2, to get s^2 = -b/a. We all know that one can't just write

```
Solve[eq==0,s^2]
```

because s^2 is not a 'variable'. only s is a 'variable'. So what I do is

```
eq  = a s^2+b;
sol = First@Solve[eq==0/.s^2->z,z];
z/.sol

-(b/a)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do the above, without the intermediate variable substitution?
I tried many commands, but no success (reduce, collect, eliminate, factor. etc...).

thanks
--Nasser

Comment: What is wrong with the intermediate variable? It seems like a good solution to me - even if it is 2 lines.

Comment: @Sam, I never said something is wrong? Just was wondering if there is a command that can do it without the intermediate subs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to solve for `s` and then square it...

```
eq=a s^2+b;
sol=#^2 &@ (s/.Solve[eq==0,s])//DeleteDuplicates

Out[1]= {-(b/a)}
```

Comment: Slightly more direct, I think, would be
    DeleteDuplicates[s^2 /. Solve[a*s^2 + b == 0, s]]
    Out[89]= {-(b/a)}

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html), but it leads to other issues.
So here is your original equation:

```
In[1]:= Solve[b + a s^2 == 0, s^2]
During evaluation of In[1]:= Solve::ivar: s^2 is not a valid variable. >>
Out[1]= Solve[b + a s^2 == 0, s^2]
```

Now `Symbolize` s^2 so that the normal Mathematica evaluator treats it like any other symbol

```
In[2]:= Needs["Notation`"]
In[3]:= Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["s", "2"]]]

In[4]:= Solve[b + a s^2 == 0, s^2]

Out[4]= {{s^2 -> -(b/a)}}
```

The problem is that s^2 really is treated as just another symbol, eg

```
In[6]:= Sqrt[s^2] // PowerExpand
Out[6]= Sqrt[s^2]
```

A work around is to replace s^2 with s*s, since `Symbolize` only acts on user inputed expressions (ie at the level of interpreting inputted Box structures)

```
In[7]:= Sqrt[s^2] /. s^2 -> s s // PowerExpand
Out[7]= s
```

Comment: Note that In[3] above was created with the Notation Palette - so you don't see all of the `Box` stuff in the Mathematica notebook.

Comment: Simon, if you can make the `Symbolize` operation temporary as in `Block` or `Module` I will vote for this.  Otherwise, it seems like hitting a nail with a sledgehammer.